# Outsource mount of HDD

Tags: hard-disk

Not sure if this is sane, but.

I'm having some issues with a HDD. It is a storage disk - so no system files are located there. The problem is related to read/write errors as these causes kernel panic. It happens as much as twice a day and as on steroids about once a week.

I do from time to time run tasks that use the disk for heavy traffic. ("Read media.") Though the freeze (almost) always happens when the disk is idle or going from idle to work.

I have tried to isolate the sectors where the issue materializes but they seems to float around.

As this is my fourth disk in as many years that causes headache and the fact I have about 6.3% of my (low) salary to live on after bills - an investment in a new HDD is cutting deep no matter how cheap disks are today. (That was the whining part.)

My questions is if there could be a way to mount a disk in an environment where if it causes problems it does not freeze the OS. Perhaps some limit settings. Let the mount process (if there are such) run in a jail of sorts or what ever - and that that could die rather then the system as a whole. But *only* for this disk.

Hope is that mount point could get inaccessible rather then kill the system - when upon a remount or what ever could be done.

My [elephant farm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) is thriving even though the magic only happens once in a while.

Comment: As I read this question, I keep reading bits that I have no idea what there relevance is. For example but not limited to the elephants and steroids

Comment: What Operating system?